# How to fix "Loaded file has not a valid JavaScript MIME type" error in Cakephp3 application

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, assets, mime-types

My cakephp3 application showing mime type issue to load assets.

Error is:

> The script from “https://www.example.com/js/abc/myjs.min.js” was
>   loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid
>   JavaScript MIME type.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/337123/script-doesnt-load-because-of-a-javascript-mime-type-error

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've resolved my issue. my cakephp application was unable to get path of located webroot folder. So I added to add a chunk of code in root .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```